# Is Visual Studio 2010 RC ready for production?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Regarding to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/archive/2010/02/08/going-live-with-the-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx), can **visual studio 2010 RC** ready for production

I know there is already a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486021/is-visual-studio-2010-ready-for-production-closed) question here, but that was asked when beta were available.

Comment: It's sort of an irrelevant question. You could ask "is VS 2008 ready for production" and get the same answer. Test and determine for yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RC is release candidate... means if no major crashers are reported this will be the build that would go out for production. Thus, you may use it at your own risk. But, per Microsoft, do NOT use it for production.

Comment: Actually, Microsoft seems to be releasing the RC with a 'go live' license which means you can use it for production (they did the same with the Beta2 release).  Whether you would want to (or should) is an entirely different question that really needs to be evaluated by the end user.

Comment: Usual pre-release caveats apply but: "We hope that you will consider using VS2010 RC for “go live” production purposes. As you use the release, we want to hear from you at our Connect site if you find any bugs." - http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/archive/2010/02/08/going-live-with-the-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx

Comment: While it is licensed for production use, it is still very unstable.

Answer (score 4):

I work for a .NET component vendor ([Syncfusion, Inc](http://www.syncfusion.com)). We work for long cycles on pre-release code and have been very happy with Visual Studio 2010 RC. We had no trouble moving our code over. IDE integration features worked perfectly. It is a sweet upgrade especially if you are working with WPF, Silverlight or ASP.NET MVC. I would certainly say that Visual Studio 2010 RC is ready for prime time.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't start building a mission critical application using .NET 4.0 just yet.  I'd use it to see some of the new features and get comfortable with it [as microsoft always love to move things around].

This is an entirely new runtime they've built, so it's a much bigger chance than 2.0 to 3.5.

So, basically, don't bet your career on it just yet but definitely use it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using VS2010 pre-RC for a few months working on a fairly demanding WPF application. It's ready, and it's awesome; I don't even have VS2008 installed on my machine anymore.

Comment: Is VS 2010 able to keep compatible with 2008 solution files?  or do you need to upgrade the SLN to use 2010?

Comment: You do have to upgrade the solution file, but they will still open just fine in VS2008, unlike previous upgrades where it would no longer open in the older version

Answer (score 1):

As of the Release Candidate, anyone running Windows XP Service Pack 2 is now locked out of Visual Studio 2010. I cannot upgrade this work computer to SP3 which is a huge pain in the ass as now I cannot use VS2010 unless Microsoft circumvents this dependency on SP3 via a patch.

Many big corporations upgrade their systems very, very slowly and thus Microsoft has locked out a lot of people not able to run SP3 from using it.

Comment: Can you post a link to where SP3 is a requirement? However, I wouldn't blame Microsoft for requiring it. It's been out for quite a long time now, and there's very little excuse for not having upgraded to it, even if you work for a big, slow corporation or government.

Comment: I know that myself, but I highly doubt one puny employee like me will be able to make them budge. Maybe on *my* workstation only.. The requirement is shown when you try to install it. Says that SP3 is a requirement to proceed.